# Using typedef function defined in C dll in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I got a project.dll and header file. It is defined like that:

```
#ifdef PPSDK_EXPORTS
#define PP_SDK_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define PP_SDK_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
#ifndef __PP_SDK__
#define __PP_SDK__

typedef enum
{
    PP_FALSE= 0x0,
    PP_TRUE = 0x01
} pp_bool;

PP_SDK_API pp_bool SDK_Initialize(unsigned long*p_Status );
```

I use some helps on google and on this web for using this dll in C# but it is not successful. 
It is error on pp_bool type.
This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        [DllImport("project.dll")]
        static extern  pp_bool  SDK_Initialize(unsigned long*p_Status );
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```

......................................
Can you help me how to handle it.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to determine the type of `pp_bool`. Since it's an `enum`, the compiler is allowed to use whatever integer type it wants as long as that type can fit all the values (and isn't bigger than int unless it has to be) -- so it could be bool, short, int, char, etc. You'll need to print out `sizeof(pp_bool)` to find out what type your specific compiler is using, then match that with an equivalently sized integer type in C#. Also, on the C# side `unsigned long*` should be `ref uint` (assuming a 32-bit long in the C code).

Answer (score 0):

Your P/Invoke definition doesn't work because the `pp_bool` type doesn't exist in C#.   The problem is that an the size of an `enum` is determined by the compiler in C++, so we can't know for sure what the size is.  It could be a `byte` an `short` on an `int`.  Although if it was compiled in Visual C++ as C code [it looks like it would be an `int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/whbyts4t.aspx).  My recommendation would be to try each of these and determine which works.

You could also try to declare the return value as a `bool` which would be the natrual .NET type.  However by [default that assumes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2t3725f.aspx) the return value is 32 bits (int size).

There is another error in your P/Invoke definition in C++ on Windows, `long` is a 32 bit value, while in .NET a `long` is 64 bits.   So your `p_Status` should be a `uint` not an `unsigned long`

Also if he `SDK_Initialize` function is only returning a single `unsigned long` value, you don't need to use a pointer.  Use a `ref` parameter instead.  The marshaller will take care of the conversion and you don't have to use unsafe code.

Finally the you need to move your p/Invoke definition.  The `[STAThread]` attribute should be on the `Main()` method, not on your p/Invoke definition.  Not to mention the documentation comments for `Main()` are being applied to `SDK_Initialize`.

So it should be something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("project.dll")]
        static extern bool SDK_Initialize(ref uint p_Status );

        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }
    }
}
```